# Can I Query the Android Market to Return Apps with Specific Permissions?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

Is it possible to query the Android Market to return apps with a 
specific set of permissions? This would be a HUGE help to me.

I've heard of an open-source API project in the works (http://groups.google.com/group/android-market-api), but I'm not sure if it will provide the exact functionality for what I'm looking for.

Any information is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You got it right.. http://groups.google.com/group/android-market-api helps you to get the set of permission. The structure will be as following text:

```
Response : app {
  id: 
  title: 
  appType: 
  creator: 
  version: 
  rating: 
  ratingsCount: 
  ExtendedInfo {
    description: 
    downloadsCount: 
    permissionId: 
    permissionId: 
    installSize: 
    packageName: 
    category: 
    downloadsCountText: 
    contactWebsite:
    screenshotsCount: 
    promoText: 
    19: 
    28: 
    36: 
    37: 
  }
  creatorId: 
  packageName: 
  versionCode: 
}
```