# Is it possible to query the android market to find apps with given hardware features?

Tags: android

I know that it is possible to do this for permissions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486413/can-i-query-the-android-market-to-return-apps-with-specific-permissions) and more generally (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557300/finding-a-list-of-all-the-android-apps-on-the-market).

The question I'm asking is related but different:

***"Which list of applications utilize the phone's accelerometer?"***  etc

I have successfully used the android-market-api to search for permissions which may imply certain features, but a direct search would be better.

As an aside, I'd be interested to know if anyone has insight into what Google's market justification is for locking down the android market.

Comment: There is no authorized API for getting any information from the Android Market. The techniques documented in those answers involve pirating data from Google; hence, use of those techniques is not a very smart idea.

Comment: LOL yeah, it seems borderline sketchy.  Unfortunate, because I need this data for legitimate research purposes.